# Problema al pasar una variable(array) por ajax [object Object] ""

Tags: ajax

Tengo un problema con ajax

al pasar una variable json para ajax, los datos que se envian me un [object Object] ""

```
datos={d:JSON.stringify(n)};
donde 
n=Object { 0: {…}, 1: {…}, 2: {…}, 3: {…}, 4: {…}, 5: {…}, … }
Object { nombre: "x1", valor: "2022-01-26" }
Object { nombre: "x2", valor: "RICARDO " }
Object { nombre: "x3", valor: "HUERTAS" }
Object { nombre: "x4", valor: "RODRIGUEZ" }
Object { nombre: "x5", valor: "2022-01-24" }
Object { nombre: "x6", valor: "1" }
Object { nombre: "x7", valor: "3" }

llamado a funcion

ajax(datos, pag, b); 

function ajax(z, a, b, c){ // URL, callback, just a placeholder
    c = new XMLHttpRequest;
    c.open('POST', a);
    c.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    c.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest')
    c.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json, text/javascript, */*');
    c.setRequestHeader("Content-length", z.length);
    c.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    c.onload = b;
    c.send(z);
  }
​
```

en la solicitud de datos del formulario me arroja

```
[object Object] "
```

es decir no envia nada.

Por favor me pueden decir  donde tengo el error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta poner los `setRequestHeader()` antes del `send()`.

```js
var object = {
  name: "Carlos",
  apellido: "Muñoz",
  edad: 15
  fecha: "11/1/2022"
};

var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open(metodo, url);
ajax.onload = function() {};

ajax.setRequestHeader(
  "Content-Type",
  "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

ajax.send("ObjectDatos=" + JSON.stringify(object));
```

Comment: Gracias, funciono.